# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

All,

I have below `Pandas` dataframe, and I am trying to filter my dataframe such that my output displays country name along with the year 1989 column whose number is >1000000.For this I am using below code, but it is returning me below error.

```
{'Country': {0: 'Austria', 1: 'Belgium', 2: 'Denmark', 3: 'Finland', 4: 'France', 5: 'Germany', 6: 'Iceland', 7: 'Ireland', 8: 'Italy', 9: 'Luxemburg', 10: 'Netherland', 11: 'Norway', 12: 'Portugal', 13: 'Spain', 14: 'Sweden', 15: 'Switzerland', 16: 'United Kingdom'}, 'y1989': {0: 7602431, 1: 9927600, 2: 5129800, 3: 4954359, 4: 56269800, 5: 61715000, 6: 253500, 7: 3526600, 8: 57504700, 9: 374900, 10: 14805240, 11: 4226901, 12: 10304700, 13: 38851900, 14: 8458890, 15: 6619973, 16: 57236200}, 'y1990': {0: 7660345.0, 1: 9947800.0, 2: 5135400.0, 3: 4974383.0, 4: 0.0, 5: 62678000.0, 6: 255708.0, 7: 3505500.0, 8: 57576400.0, 9: 379300.0, 10: 14892574.0, 11: 4241473.0, 12: 0.0, 13: 38924500.0, 14: 8527040.0, 15: 6673850.0, 16: 57410600.0}, 'y1991': {0: 7790957, 1: 9987000, 2: 5146500, 3: 4998478, 4: 56893000, 5: 79753000, 6: 259577, 7: 3519000, 8: 57746200, 9: 384400, 10: 15010445, 11: 4261930, 12: 9858500, 13: 38993800, 14: 8590630, 15: 6750693, 16: 57649200}, 'y1992': {0: 7860800, 1: 10068319, 2: 5162100, 3: 5029300, 4: 57217500, 5: 80238000, 6: 262193, 7: 3542000, 8: 57788200, 9: 389800, 10: 15129200, 11: 4273634, 12: 9846000, 13: 39055900, 14: 8644100, 15: 6831900, 16: 58888800}, 'y1993': {0: 7909575, 1: 10100631, 2: 5180614, 3: 5054982, 4: 57529577, 5: 81338000, 6: 264922, 7: 3559985, 8: 57114161, 9: 395200, 10: 15354000, 11: 4324577, 12: 9987500, 13: 39790955, 14: 8700000, 15: 6871500, 16: 58191230}, 'y1994': {0: 7943652, 1: 10130574, 2: 5191000, 3: 5098754, 4: 57847000, 5: 81353000, 6: 266783, 7: 3570700, 8: 57201800, 9: 400000, 10: 15341553, 11: 4348410, 12: 9776000, 13: 39177400, 14: 8749000, 15: 7021200, 16: 58380000}, 'y1995': {0: 8054800, 1: 10143047, 2: 5251027, 3: 5116800, 4: 58265400, 5: 81845000, 6: 267806, 7: 3591200, 8: 57268578, 9: 412800, 10: 15492800, 11: 4370000, 12: 9920800, 13: 39241900, 14: 8837000, 15: 7060400, 16: 58684000}}
```

**My code**

```
df[(df.Country)& (df.y1989>1000000)]
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'
```

I am not sure what could be the reason, being a newbie to python if you could provide explanation for the error that will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'Country'` doesn't form part of your filtering criteria, so don't use it to form your Boolean indexer. Instead, use the `loc` accessor to give a Boolean condition *and* specify necessary columns separately:

```
res = df.loc[df['y1989'] > 1000000, ['Country','y1989']]
```

**Under no circumstances use chained assignment**, e.g. via `df[df['y1989']>1000000][['Country','y1989']]`, as this is ambiguous and [explicitly discouraged in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy).

Comment: Thanks for sharing why its actually not as efficient

Comment: @jpp.. Thanks! Just so I understand correctly. Since, 'Country' doesn't have to meet boolean condtion. It is safe to use .loc ?

Comment: @biggboss2019, Sure. I see no reason why not.